# Getting errors while Firebase cloud function deployment

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a stripe blaze plan and I'm implementing stripe payments. I'm trying to deploy firebase cloud functions with the command firebase deploy --only functions,

[image]

but it shows the below error.

Error:

i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Function URL (api(us-central1)): https://us-central1-bookify-7a0fa.cloudfunctions.net/api
Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
api(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
firebase deploy --only "functions:api"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

I've tried many rename and deploy technique but it didn't work at all. Please suggest me a solution. It would be a great help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you try `firebase deploy --only "functions:api --debug` and share the logs ?

Comment: Function URL (api(us-central1)): https://us-central1-bookify-7a0fa.cloudfunctions.net/api

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        api(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:api"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions
[2021-09-09T07:32:47.790Z]      Error during update for projects/bookify-7a0fa/locations/us-central1/functions/api:

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.

Comment: did you ever resolve the issue?